# How to dismiss modal view controller and refresh previous view controller

Tags: swift

I have simple qr code scanner (using Avfoundation). When qr code is detected it stop capturing and present information view controller over scanner view controller (not full screen). But when I dismiss information view controller I can't start capturing again (apearance methods are not called). Any ideas how to fix it?

Controller A presenting controller B:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "customViewAlert", bundle: nil)
let vc = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(
            vc,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil
        )
```

Controller A delegation:

```
extension ViewController: ModalHandler {
    func modalDismissed() {
        self.captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}
```

Controller B dismiss:

```
@IBAction func closeButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
  delegate?.modalDismissed()
  dismiss(
    animated: true,
    completion: nil
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the delegate

```
let vc = sb.instantiateInitialViewController()!
vc.delegate = self
```